# Introducir palabra por teclado y buscarla en fichero en lenguaje linux (SSH)

Tags: ssh, grep

estoy trabajando con SSH, y tengo el siguiente problema.

Estoy usando ficheros de texto (con contenido escrito dentro de ellos) y quería saber si hay alguna forma de que yo pida una palabra concreta por teclado y aparezcan todos los ficheros que contengan dicha palabra.

De momento lo único que he encontrado es que se ejecute una palaba que ponga yo por código, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

`grep -l palabra ./*`

Pero para leer una palabra que un usuario introduzca he probado esto y no funciona:

```
   echo "Escribe la palabra" 
   read var1
   grep -l $var1 ./*
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo o si es posible?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: SSH no es un lenguaje, es un concepto usado para conexiones remotas entre dispositivos.

Comment: Linux es un sistema operativo y SSH es un protocolo para conexión remota. Asumimos entonces que estás en una terminal bash?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tratar con el siguiente codigo en tu bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Ingrese palabra a buscar"
read word
echo "Ingrese el path"
read path
grep -rnw "$word" $path
```

- `-r` o `-R` es recursivo
- `-n` es el numero de linea
- `-w` espera el match completo de la palabra.

No olvides correrlo como SUDO para evitar problemas de permisos.

Puedes encontrar la referencia original en [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/how-do-i-find-all-files-containing-specific-text-on-linux)